# CakePHP 3 how to save related association 1:N in the right way using REST?

Tags: cakephp, orm, marshalling

I would like to ask how to save related data using REST in CakePHP3?

Lest assume that I have following association Command can have many related tags (see EER diagram below please).

[image]

JSON request structure is the following:

```
{
    "command": "whoami",
    "description": "SOMETHING",
    "public": false,
    "tags": [
        {"name":"TEST1"},
        {"name":"TEST2"}
    ]
}
```

I tried to implement saving in associations using

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations

But without the luck.

So I did it in the following way:

```
public function add()
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post']);
        $data = $this->request->getData();
        $user = $this->CommonHelper->getUserByToken($this->token);
        $command = $this->Commands->newEntity($data);
        $tags = $data['tags'];
        $command->user = $user;
        $command = $this->Commands->patchEntity($command, $data);
        if ($this->Commands->save($command)) {
            if($tags != null)
                $this->addTags($tags, $command);//TODO: DO IT IN THE RIGHT WAY WITH MARSHALLING
            $this->apiResponse['data'] = $command;
            $this->httpStatusCode = 200;
        } else {
            $this->httpStatusCode = 400;
        }
    }

    private function addTags($tags, $command)
    {
        foreach ($tags as $value) {
            $tag = $this->Tags->newEntity($value);
            $tag->commands_id = $command->id;
            $this->Tags->save($tag);
        }
    }
```

But this is an only ad-hoc solution, I would like to do it in the right way with use possibilities of CakePHP ORM architecture.

Tags table definition is following:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('tags');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Commands', [
            'foreignKey' => 'commands_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You show that your `Tags` table has a `belongsTo` association with `Commands`. But does `Commands` have a corresponding `hasMany` association with `Tags`?

Comment: No, it does not have hasMany assoc. I thought that this assoc should be added automatically based on the EER scheme (SQL struct) during the baking the model in console. It means that using $this->hasMany('Tags'); I can use insertion to the related tables automatically based pn the provided JSON data?

Comment: Your schema doesn't follow [**CakePHP's naming conventions**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#database-conventions), foreign keys should be singular, hence baking won't work properly. Manually added associations also won't work unless you'd explicitly specify the irregular foreign key.

Comment: Thanks, now it works out of box.

Answer (score 1):

You can save associated data in this way. 
Your data array should be like in this format.

```
$data = array(
    "command"=> "whoami",
    "description"=> "SOMETHING",
    "public"> false,
    "tags": [
        array("name" => "TEST1"),
        array("name"=> "TEST2")
    ]
)

$patchedEntity= $this->Commands->patchEntity($saveData,$data,['associated' => ['Tags']]); 
$result = $this->Commands->save($patchedEntity);
```

Define the relations in Commands table should be like this.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config); 
        $this->setTable('commands');  
        $this->hasMany('Tags', [
            'foreignKey' => 'command_id'
        ]);
    }
```

Relation in Tags table should be like this.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config); 
        $this->setTable('tags');  
        $this->belongsTo('Commands', [
            'foreignKey' => 'command_id'
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was given by bad naming conventions in the model. Using singular in foreign key helped me solved the problem.